# deep learning for multi label with numerical featurs

Tags: regression

i am working in a project where my input data are color images and the output data is 12 parameters which are numerical values not pinary.
any suggestion about
labels of images
number of output layer nodes

Comment: any suggestion about labels of images and  number of output layer nodes

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of the inputs and outputs to this model? Specifically, I think I am most confused about the outputs.

Comment: i have 8 parameters A1,A2,......,A8. each one hase its range for example A1(0.1 to 1.5) and A2(25 to 70) i will devide each parameter into 5 points. so i have 8 to the power 5 different cases. for each case i have one image. i want to use a deep learning as follwos, images are the input of the deep learning model and the output will be the values of the 8 parameters.